# How to implement a user selectable theme / style in react native?

Tags: dynamic, react-native, styles, themes

If user has selected light-theme, and switches to dark-theme, then all scenes will immediately render to using the dark-theme.

I am using react-native-router-flux if this helps.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6):

Different approaches are possible. One of them is to use React [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). Generally it should be used with caution but theming is one of the official examples where it is suitable.

> Theming is a good example of when you might want an entire subtree to have access to some piece of information

So the example might look like

```
class App extends Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return {theme: { primaryColor: "purple" }};
  }
  ...
}
App.childContextTypes = {
  theme: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

where you set the context for rest of your application and then you use it in your components

```
class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={this.context.theme.primaryColor}>...
  }
}
Button.contextTypes = {
  theme: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

If you want to switch theme, you can set context based on your state/props that can be based on user selection.

Currently we are dealing with same questions and therefore we have starting prototyping library called [react-native-themeable](https://github.com/instea/react-native-themeable).

The idea is to use context to store theme and (re)implement RN components so they can replace original components but supports theming.

Example of theme switching you can find in https://github.com/instea/react-native-themeable/blob/master/examples/src/SwitchTheme.js

Comment: The React context approach is interesting. Other approaches such as react-native-material-kit and https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase seem to be taking a theme-able component approach.  This is good for new app development I suppose.  For existing apps, not so much.  The  React context approach works.  I will see if I can make it dynamically change.  Thank you very much!

Comment: This does not seem to work for more than one child component deep ?

Comment: Never mind, I am reading the link https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how to pass it down through a react-native-router-flux <Scene > component ?  Where the Scene declares the child component

Comment: yes, other libs use context approach as well. but as you said, it is better with those libs from scratch. but you can start implementing yourself context solution and gradually upgrade your components to be context aware.

Comment: no, context works more the one child deep. just make sure you did everything as you need (e.g. defining `contextTypes` etc).

Comment: I am not familiar with RN-router-flux, but if you set context in our top most component, it should be propagated everywhere.

Comment: Context works more than one child deep.  Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating one JS file containing two objects that have the colors for each theme. Then just use one as a default and if the user picks another theme save it in the database or using local storage and pull the relevant object.

```
export const theme1 = {
     blue: '#fddd',
     red: '#ddddd',
     buttonColor: '#fff'
 }

export const theme2 = {
     blue: '#fddd',
     red: '#ddddd'
     buttonColor: '#fff'
 }
```

Then just import the relevant file:

```
import * as themes from 'Themes'
const currentTheme = this.props.currentTheme ? this.props.currentTheme : 'theme1'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   button: {
     color: themes[currentTheme].buttonColor
   },

})
```

Comment: The theme is only selected once in your code - on app start. The app cannot be rerendered with a new theme on-the-fly using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn’t it be great if you could import a colors object directly, and modify the object every time you change the theme and have those new colors propagate to the entire app? Then your components wouldn’t need to have any special theme logic. I was able to achieve this using a combination of AsyncStorage, forced app restart, and async module loading.

Comment: Hi Rarecandy, welcome to SO!  We like specifics here, so please expand upon your answer to provide more detail.  For example, paste in the code you used or write out the steps you went through (e.g., what menu options did you click on in a GUI, in what order) to solve the OP's question.  Ideally, using the OP's minimum working example, if they have provided one. Try to make it as easy as possible for the OP to replicate your steps and evaluate whether your answer solves their question.